# Upvoting a -1 goes to 1 not 0, why?

Tags: support, voting

If I downvote an answer with 0 votes, it goes down to -1. I changed my mind and I upvote it and it goes up to 1 instead of 0. If I upvote one more time, it goes down to 0.

What's the logic behind this, what I consider weird counterintuitive, behavior?

Comment: I just made your votes go from 1 to -1!

Comment: It does seem counter intuitive, but consider a question downvoting from 0 to -1. You upvote it after an edit. It goes from -1 to 1. You are essentially cancelling out your original vote as if the downvote never happened. It is one or the other, not both.

Comment: No hard feelings, it can be confusing.

Comment: Put your mouse above the vote buttons and read the tooltip. Yes, to undo the vote, just click once again at the same button!

Comment: This has got to be trolling.

Answer (score 14):

You can't vote both up and down.

When you upvote the post, your downvote is automatically removed.

Comment: This confused me the first time too. I thought that clicking the up button would remove the downvote, but not so. Clicking downvote again removes the downvote. Clicking upvote removes the downvote AND adds an upvote.

Comment: I am not doing both. What does this even mean logically!? The way I vision this is 0 is between -1 & 1. 1 is above 0 and -1 is below 0 and that's how I operate.

Comment: @Tony: THe furst upvote cancels the downvote; the second upvote cancels the first upvote.  The voting arrows are mutually-exclusive toggle buttons.

Answer (score 5):

If you downvote an answer it goes to -1.  Your vote isn't instantly finalized and you can only cast one vote per question, so when you upvote it it changes your initial vote of the question to +1.  Pushing the upvote button again cancels your upvote and the post returns to it's initial 0.

Answer (score 3):

To add a bit more to these answers, Consider the following:

1. Click downvote.............Now it's **-1**.
2. Click downvote again...Now it's **0**.
3. Click upvote.................Now it's **+1**.
4. Click upvote again.......Now it's **0.**

Essentially, when you click downvote, and then click the upvote, you are implicitly performing *three* actions (not just the first two).

The premise here is that it makes more sense to go from -1 to +1 to minimize the number of clicks if you voted in the wrong direction.  It might make more sense to change the arrow (up or down) to an **X** to more clearly signify cancel, but my hunch is that most would rather simply leave the interface unchanged.